# List cross-referencing causing lag in c#

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I have a game kinda like minecraft, but from a top down perspective, adding blocks is done by when the player left-clicks it adds the block at the specified position, right-clicking on a placed block deletes the block.

The problem I was having was that when the player left-clicks it adds the block and its position to a list (for saving to XML later), so the logical conclusion is that when the player *right-clicks* it removes said block from the game, and its position from its list.

This is the method that I was using which generated lag:

```
for (int b = 0; b < game.blocklist.Count; b++)
{
    for (int v = 0; v < game.blockpos1.Count; v++)
    {
        if (game.blocklist[b].visible == true)
        {
            if (game.cursor.boundingbox.Intersects(game.blocklist[b].blockrectangle) && mousestate.RightButton == ButtonState.Pressed && game.player.Builder == true)
            {
                if (game.blocklist[b].blockposition.X == game.blockpos1[v].X && game.blocklist[b].blockposition.Y == game.blockpos1[v].Y)
                {
                    game.blockpos1.RemoveAt(v);
                    game.blocklist.RemoveAt(b);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now this is the method that I replaced it with which reduces lag immensely and still achieves the same effect I want:

```
for (int b = 0; b < game.blocklist.Count; b++)
{
    if (game.blocklist[b].visible == true)
    {
        if (game.cursor.boundingbox.Intersects(game.blocklist[b].blockrectangle) && mousestate.RightButton == ButtonState.Pressed && game.player.Builder == true)
        {
            if (game.blocklist[b].blockposition.X == game.blockpos1[b].X && game.blocklist[b].blockposition.Y == game.blockpos1[b].Y)
            {
                game.blockpos1.RemoveAt(b);
                game.blocklist.RemoveAt(b);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why does this generate so much lag? I just need clarification as to what I did wrong so I don't do it again.

Comment: You appear to have effectively halved the execution time of this method. You had two loops that can be substituted for a single loop and continue to adhere to your requirements.. welcome to the world of refactoring :)

Answer (score 1):

```
  for (int b = 0; b < game.blocklist.Count; b++)
            {
                for (int v = 0; v < game.blockpos1.Count; v++)
            {

                    if (game.blocklist[b].visible == true)
                    {
```

in this version, basically for every item in blocklist ( X ) whether it was visible or not you are iterating every item in blockpos1 (Y).    So you do X * Y loops.  You then reduced it to X loops and only evaluated visible items.

Given the way the code is written in the question,  I'd check these two things before even trying to loop

```
mousestate.RightButton == ButtonState.Pressed && game.player.Builder == true
```

because they will never change during those loops. so if they aren't true to start with, don't even bother looping.

Also as Preseton says in the comments, no need to compare things to true.... you only need to do

```
mousestate.RightButton == ButtonState.Pressed && game.player.Builder
```

and

```
if (game.blocklist[b].visible)
```

Comment: Additonally, wisdom of having a bool named `Builder` aside, `someBooleanValue == true` is always the same as `someBooleanValue` alone.